# When to use form actions vs. on:submit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am currently learning Svelte and SvelteKit and so far I like it.

However one thing that puzzles me a bit is the question when I should use [form actions](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions) and when should I use a simple `on:submit` handler?

Are there different use cases?
Or maybe they can be both used at the same time?
What should I do if I want to send JSON data to an external API?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 8):

A major difference between form actions and `on:submit` is form actions are intended to work without JS; `on:submit` will not work if JS is disabled/broken.

**So SvelteKit encourages using form actions whenever possible to provide the optimal user browsing experience.**

If you want to send JSON data to an external API, there are a few options including:

- Call the external API directly from the client (browser). Probably the simplest option, but not recommended if private API keys are exposed anywhere in the URL/payload. Also this will probably not work if JS is disabled or broken.
- Wrap the API with a [SvelteKit +server route](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server), which calls the external API from the server (vs. from the client above). This helps prevent leaking private API keys, but still will not work if JS is disabled or broken.
- Call the API from a form action. Form actions don't take JSON as input though; they take [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) as input. So the action should construct the JSON from the form inputs.

Answer (score 4):

If the access to the external APIs has to happen from the server (e.g. because of non-disclosed credentials), using a form action is recommended.

Ideally with SvelteKit one should use the [`enhance` action](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement) which allows the page to be updated with response data without a full reload automatically (data is set to the `form` property) and with form actions the page should still work even if JS fails to load/is disabled, then with a regular form post.

There should rarely be any reason to handle `submit`, the `enhance` action can also be used to intercept the submission and e.g. add additional data to the request.

If you want to go directly to the external API from the browser, then intercepting it makes sense and allows you to send a custom JSON request if the API does not support regular form encoded data.

Comment: So e.g. a login request to a non-protected endpoint should be done via `on:submit` handler - am I understanding correctly?

Comment: It can be, yes. May depend a bit on the API as well, some even require that the user's client sends the request directly to set certain cookies as far as I know. Also, even *protected* endpoints may be accessed if the credentials being used are those provided by the user (e.g. cookies) and not some secret key provided by your application. I am not an expert on various authentication protocols involving third party providers, but I could also imagine a flow where it *has* to go through the server and a response may contain something only intended for said server.

Comment: If the API is something provided as an external commercial service, there usually would be documentation explaining where from and how requests should be sent.

Answer (score 2):

While form actions are very useful and handy, in reality you might want your webapp to be deployed with `adapter-static` for better performance and/or hosting with providers like Cloudflare.

If that's the case, you'll need to use endpoints (`+server.js`) and `fetch` rather than `+page.server.js` files to hanlde all your back-end operations.

I find my reason more important to base the decision on than the other two answers, though they still valid to some point.

Answer (score 0):

In my recent app, I even do one level down, and I use `on:click` to handle the `POST` action of a form.

1. I have a page showing all the details of a book, including the tags.
2. I have a modal that pops up to ask the user to input a few tags of that book by his own.
3. Then I insert any 'new' tags into the database.

I use PHP to develop the backend API. I use `on:click` is because I think this saves me a lot of time. The code snippet is quite straightforward.

```
<Modal bind:open={popupModal} size="xs" autoclose={false} class="w-full">
  <form class="flex flex-col space-y-6" method="post">
    <h3 class="text-xl font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white p-0">
      为《{book.title}》添加tag
    </h3>
    <Label class="space-y-2">
      <span>Tags（用空格分隔）</span>
      <Input type="text" name="tags" bind:value={finalTags} required />
      <Input type="hidden" name="id" value={book.id} />
    </Label>
    <Button type="button" on:click={doPost} class="w-full1">创建新的TAG</Button>
  </form>
</Modal>
```

And then in the `doPost()` function:

```
async function doPost() {
    const inputTags = finalTags.trim().split(" ");
    const oldTags = tags;
    const difference = inputTags.filter((x) => !oldTags.includes(x));
    const insert = difference.join(" ");
    const res = await fetch(
      form_uri,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          'id': book.id,
          'tags': insert,
        }),
      }
    );
    const json = await res.json();
    location.reload();
  }
```

So I can refresh the page after any tags being inserted.

Just my thoughts.