# How do I make a call to a protected external API from SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit frontend client for a chat app. The idea is to make a post request to my API endpoint which is completely separate. What method should I use to make this API call?

I've looked at Form Actions, Load, and just a regular fetch client-side.

I don't know which one is best despite looking at similar posts like [When to use form actions vs. on:submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75610038/when-to-use-form-actions-vs-onsubmit)

Note: Only authenticated users should be allowed to submit messages to the endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the SvelteKit app is not entirely pre-rendered, use `<form>` and [form actions](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions).

1. Protected external API probably means that it has to be authenticated with a secret.
2. Add the secret to the `.env` file and import it using `$env/static/private`.
3. This secret stays in the server, and is not sent to the client at all.

When the user submits the form,

1. Check if the user is authenticated in the server hooks.
2. If authenticated, fill the `event.locals` in the `handle` fn.
3. In the action fn, check the `event.locals` and check if it's valid.
4. If valid, send a fetch request to the external API by including the secret.

Comment: Thanks, so what I've done is set the user auth as a svelte store. Then in my page.svelte I get the value of the stored $user and user firebase's getIdToken() and store it as a variable inside the script tags. 

Then in the form, I use formData.append(token)

I'm not sure how to use hooks in this case, is it an alternative to what I've done?

Comment: If the external API is completely separate, and if the client already has the auth token accessible using JavaScript, `on:submit` could be a viable option in this case.

Comment: @Hyunbin, what happens to the .env file and its contents if this app is deployed via SST in a serverless fashion on to AWS? Where does .env go?